# Geodesic flow on a compact manifold is defined for all time

Tags: dynamical-systems, riemannian-geometry

How can I prove that on a compact manifold, the geodesic flow is defined for all time? Is this as simple as citing the Hopf-Rinow theorem?

Answer (score 4):

Besides Hopf-Rinow you can use a general fact. Namely that the flow of a vector field defined on a compact manifold is complete i.e. defined for all time. Then you should know that the geodesic flow is defined by a vector field (some times called *spray*) defined on the unit tangent bundle of the compact manifold. Such unit tangent bundle is also compact hence the geodesic flow is complete.